# Pages exist. Browser works fine but w3c link validator shows 404 error

Tags: http-status-code-404

I am facing a strange issue with pages being shown fine in browser. However, on W3C link validator or any other broken link validators, all the links show up as 404 not found. The website is https://www.hexadesigns.in - what might be the cause? The .htaccess is as below:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hexadesigns.in/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hexadesigns.in/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^blog/wp-admin/$ blog/wp-login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-.&,_']+)/$  ../blog-article.php?e=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([A-Za-z0-9-.&,_']+)/$  ../blog/index.php?e=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9-.&,_']+)/([0-9-.&,_']+)/$  ../blog/index.php?s=$1&m=$2 [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /page-404.php
```